# How to reformat code, adding a new line before a line separator "\n in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have this function:

case1:

```
public function searchArticle($keyword)
{
    $keyword = sanitize($keyword, 15);

    $sql = "SELECT a.*, c.id as cid, c.name" . Lang::$lang . " as catname, a.title" . Lang::$lang . " as atitle, c.slug as catslug, u.username,"
        . "\n (SELECT COUNT(artid) FROM " . self::cmTable . " WHERE artid = a.id) as totalcomments, YEAR(a.created) as year, MONTH(a.created) as month, DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%d') as day,"
        . "\n (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT participant) FROM " . self::partTable . " WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,a.participants) > 0)as participants"
        . "\n FROM " . self::mTable . " as a"
        . "\n LEFT JOIN " . self::ctTable . " as c ON c.id = a.cid" . "\n LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.uid"
        . "\n WHERE MATCH (title" . Lang::$lang . ", body" . Lang::$lang . ") AGAINST ('" . self::$db->escape($keyword) . "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
        . "\n AND a.created <= NOW()" . "\n AND (a.expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.expire >= NOW())"
        . "\n AND a.active = 1"
        . "\n ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 20";
    $row = self::$db->fetch_all($sql);

    return ($row) ? $row : 0;
}
```

Every line is as it should be.

Now, when I use code reformat option this code style looks like this:

case2:

```
public function searchArticle($keyword)
{
    $keyword = sanitize($keyword, 15);

    $sql = "SELECT a.*, c.id as cid, c.name" . Lang::$lang . " as catname, a.title" . Lang::$lang . " as atitle, c.slug as catslug, u.username," . "\n (SELECT COUNT(artid) FROM " . self::cmTable . " WHERE artid = a.id) as totalcomments, YEAR(a.created) as year, MONTH(a.created) as month, DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%d') as day," . "\n (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT participant) FROM " . self::partTable . " WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,a.participants) > 0)as participants" . "\n FROM " . self::mTable . " as a" . "\n LEFT JOIN " . self::ctTable . " as c ON c.id = a.cid" . "\n LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.uid" . "\n WHERE MATCH (title" . Lang::$lang . ", body" . Lang::$lang . ") AGAINST ('" . self::$db->escape($keyword) . "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" . "\n AND a.created <= NOW()" . "\n AND (a.expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.expire >= NOW())" . "\n AND a.active = 1" . "\n ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 20";
    $row = self::$db->fetch_all($sql);

    return ($row) ? $row : 0;
}
```

The closest I can get is to set "Binary expressions" to "wrap always" in "Preferences/Code Style/PHP/Wapping and Braces", but it is still not as it should be and it is not really well readable.

case3:

```
public function searchArticle($keyword)
{
    $keyword = sanitize($keyword, 15);

    $sql =
        "SELECT a.*, c.id as cid, c.name" .
        Lang::$lang .
        " as catname, a.title" .
        Lang::$lang .
        " as atitle, c.slug as catslug, u.username," .
        "\n (SELECT COUNT(artid) FROM " .
        self::cmTable .
        " WHERE artid = a.id) as totalcomments, YEAR(a.created) as year, MONTH(a.created) as month, DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%d') as day," .
        "\n (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT participant) FROM " .
        self::partTable .
        " WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,a.participants) > 0)as participants" .
        "\n FROM " .
        self::mTable .
        " as a" .
        "\n LEFT JOIN " .
        self::ctTable .
        " as c ON c.id = a.cid" .
        "\n LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.uid" .
        "\n WHERE MATCH (title" .
        Lang::$lang .
        ", body" .
        Lang::$lang .
        ") AGAINST ('" .
        self::$db->escape($keyword) .
        "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" .
        "\n AND a.created <= NOW()" .
        "\n AND (a.expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.expire >= NOW())" .
        "\n AND a.active = 1" .
        "\n ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 20";
    $row = self::$db->fetch_all($sql);

    return ($row) ? $row : 0;
}
```

How can I set the code reformat settings in PhpStorm, to force a new line only before . "\n ? (As it can be seen in the case1)

Comment: You should definitely use parameters. 
1. Define the SQL query with parameters,  
2. Bind parameters 
3. Execute the query

I believe your DB class should implement a kind of `bind_param` method. If it doesn't then implement one. Or better use DB classes already available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for the string that contains the query.

You can embed the variables directly into the string (aka [variables interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)). I see you also use class static members and class constants to compose the query and they are not recognized during the string parsing. But you can still embed them using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$sql = <<< END_QUERY
    SELECT a.*, c.id as cid, c.name%s as catname, a.title%s as atitle, c.slug as catslug, u.username,
        (SELECT COUNT(artid) FROM %s WHERE artid = a.id) as totalcomments, YEAR(a.created) as year, MONTH(a.created) as month, DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%%d') as day,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT participant) FROM %s WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,a.participants) > 0)as participants
    FROM %s as a
        LEFT JOIN %s as c ON c.id = a.cid
        LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.uid
    WHERE MATCH (title%s, body%s) AGAINST ('%s*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        AND a.created <= NOW()
        AND (a.expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.expire >= NOW())
        AND a.active = 1
    ORDER BY a.created DESC
    LIMIT 20
END_QUERY;

$query = sprintf($query, Lang::$lang, Lang::$lang, self::cmTable, self::partTable, self::mTable, self::ctTable, Lang::$lang, Lang::$lang, self::$db->escape($keyword));
```

Because the percent sign (`%`) is a special character for [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), you have to double it in order to let it represent itself (`DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%d')` became `DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%%d')`).

Or you can avoid using `sprintf()` if you extract the class static properties, class constants and function calls into local variables before the string:

```
$lang    = Lang::$lang;
$cmTable = Lang::cmTable;
$kword   = self::$db->escape($keyword);
// ...
$sql = <<< END_QUERY
    SELECT a.*, c.id as cid, c.name{$lang} as catname, a.title{$lang} as atitle, c.slug as catslug, u.username,
// ...
```

This way the code formatting tools won't touch the query any more. As a bonus, the query is easier to read because it is all text, no more quotes and string concatenation.